# Show stage when Platform.setImplicitExit is false

Tags: java, javafx

I set `Platform.setImplicitExit(false);` to prevent my application being shut down when all the JavaFX windows are closed. But, now I'm unable to show the stage again when clicking on the app from the Mac OS Dock bar.

I'd like to show the stage again when the application is being clicked from the Mac OS dock bar.

I've tried by listening the `Platform.isImplicitExit()` method but it seems not what I want actually. Any help would be appreciated.

```
@Override
public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
    stage.setTitle("Hello World");

    stage.setScene(
            createScene(
                    loadMainPane()
            )
    );

    stage.show();

    Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
    stage.setResizable(false);
}
```

Comment: You will need to create a new `Stage` if the previous one has been closed, recreating the scene at the same time; that's the easy part. The other step is to react to the click event on the dock bar. My guess is that you'll need an specific OSX API to handle this case. JavaFX does not ship with platform specific APIs to the extent of my knowledge

Comment: I was searching for the dock bar API too but didn't find any. So, we've no choice for now then without creating the new `Stage`